# Elements $g,$ such as $g^{165}=1$ vs elements $g$ of order $165$ of a cyclic group $G$ of order $330$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I have a group $G=\langle a\rangle$ of order $330.$

I need to find all the elements $g\in G$ such as $g^{165}=1$ and then the elements $g$ of order $165.$

As far as I understand, $g\in G,g^{165}=1 \Leftrightarrow g\, \text{is} \, e,a^2,a^4,\dots,a^{330}$

And as for the elements of order $165$, those are only $e$ and $a^2$.

Am I correct or am I confusing something?

Comment: As you mention $a^2$ is generator of group of order 165 in G ( which is unique subgroupof order 165 in G). Now call $a^2$ as b and then find what powers of b has order 165. What can you conclude in terms of a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for the first question is correct. 
For the second question, $e$ has order $1$, so $e$ should not be there. And there are more.

Question 1. Find all $g\in G$ such that $g^{165}=1$.

> **Lemma 1.** Let $G=\langle a\rangle$ and $|G|=n$. Let $d\mid n$. Then 
>   $$\{g\in G: g^{d}=1\}=\langle a^{n/d}\rangle. $$

*Proof.* Let $n=qd$. 
Let $g\in LHS$. Then $g=a^{i}$ for some $i$. So $a^{id}=1$. Then $qd=n\mid id$. So $q\mid i$. Hence $a^{i}\in RHS$. Let $a^{qi}\in RHS$. Then $a^{qid}=1$. So $a^{qi}\in LHS$.

Let $A$ be the set of all $g\in G$ such that $g^{165}=1$. Then $A=\{g\in G:g^{165}=1\}=\langle a^{2}\rangle=\{1, a^{2}, a^{4}, a^{6},\ldots, a^{328}\}$.

Question 2. Find elements $g$ of order $165$.

> **Lemma 2.** Let $G=\langle a\rangle$ and $|G|=n$. Let $d\mid n$. Then 
>   $$|\{g\in G: g^{d}=1\}|=d. $$

*Proof.* Let $n=qd$. By Dummit and Foote page 57 Proposition 5 (2), $|a^{q}|=\frac{n}{(n,q)}=d$. By Lemma 1, the result follows.

Hence $|A|=165$. Let $B$ be the set of all $g\in G$ of order $165$. Then $B\subset A$. Since $A=\langle a^{2}\rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $165$, $B$ is the set of generators of $A$. Let $b=a^{2}$. Hence $A=\langle b\rangle$. All the generators of $A$ are elements $b^{i}$ such that $(i,165)=1$. So $B=\{a^{2i}:0\leq i\leq 165, (i,165)=1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Fact 1.** Let $G$ be an abelian group. Then for every positive integer $n$, the set
$$
\{x\in G:x^n=1\}
$$
is a subgroup of $G$.

**Fact 2.** Given a cyclic group $G$ of order $m$ and a divisor $n$ of $m$, there is a unique subgroup of $G$ having order $n$.

**Fact 3.** Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

**Fact 4.** An element of a cyclic group $G$ of order $m$ is a generator of $G$ if and only if it has order $m$.

---

Now you can put together facts 1–3. Since $a^2$ has order $165$, it generates a cyclic subgroup of order $165$.

This is where the elements having order $165$ live; since it is a cyclic group, you can use fact 4; set $b=a^2$ for simplicity and try to work out (or remember) what's the condition on $k$ so that $b^k$ is a generator of $\langle b\rangle$.

Comment: So  basically all the elements $e,a^2,a^4...a^330$ are those of order 165, if I understood correctly.
Then what is the difference between an element of order 165 and an element g, such as $g^{165}=1$?
There definitely is a difference and I did understand it like a week ago, but then forgot what was the key idea behind their difference

Comment: @Dknot No. Let's do a simpler example with $b$ of order $10$ instead.  Then $1,b,b^2,\dots,b^9$ don't all have order $10$. Only some of them: which ones?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, I got distracted by other exercises and then I finally understood what you meant. When it is about the rank of an element, it should reach neutral element for the first time when put in power of the rank. In other words for my group $a^4$ wouldn't fit because it would become neutral at 330, so it doesn't suit me